# Why isn't this simple alphanumeric regex matching with JS but it is matching on regex101?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to test the string `UNCLTEST614NESZZ`.

Using the regex `/^[a-z0-9]+$/i`.

Below is the code being used.

```
let regex = new RegExp("/^[a-z0-9]+$/i");
let match = regex.test(serial);
```

Yet `match` ends up being false, despite the same regex and test string in regex101 producing a positive result

https://regex101.com/r/MrpcB5/1

Comment: You don't use `/` when using `new RegExp(string literal)`; plus the flags must be specified in second parameter.

Comment: I think it should be like `new RegExp(/^[a-z0-9]+$/, "i");` or `new RegExp("^[a-z0-9]+$", "i");` or `/^[a-z0-9]+$/i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

You can either use

```
let regex = new RegExp("^[a-z0-9]+$", "i");
```

or

```
let regex = /^[a-z0-9]+$/i;
```